# What is the address target of "My computer" in Windows? How can I make a custom shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am trying to create a shortcut to "My computer". I don't want this shortcut on the desktop, but somewhere else. At first sight, this doesn't seem possible, since "My computer" is not an actual filesystem location.

(Using Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I am trying to create a shortcut to "My computer"

1. Click "Show Desktop"
2. Right click "My Computer" and select "Create shortcut"
3. Right click "My Computer - Shortcut" and select "Cut"
4. Open Explorer and browse to somewhere else.
5. Right click and select "Paste"

Comment: Thanks, although the solution I found cuts to the heart of the problem, and might be more useful when you need the actual "address", your solution is far more practical. The only disadvantage is that the simplicity of it makes me feel stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this over here: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=176462
This solution was provided in 2004, so seems very likely to be consistent across different Windows versions.

The following location can be used:

> C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
>   /root,,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}

In the location bar and the ctrl-R dialog, the following can be used

> ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}